# accessing github user data in meteor oauth

Tags: javascript, oauth, meteor

I am trying to authenticate a user with github, then pass their `avatar_url` to the client. Simplified structure looks as follows.

```
server/
  publications.js
client/
  users/
    login.js
  main.js
```

In my `client/users/login.js` file, I try to get the permission to the user Object which contains the avatar url

```
Accounts.ui.config({
  requestPermissions: {
    github: ['user']
  }
});
```

Then in my `server/publications.js`, I try to publish [the data related to the avatar url](https://developer.github.com/v3/users/).

```
Meteor.publish('userData', function() {
  if(this.userId) {
    return Meteor.users.find(
      { _id: this.userId }, {
      fields: {
        'services.github.id': 1,
        'services.github.user.avatar_url': 1
      }
    })
  } else {
    this.ready();
  }
});
```

However I never get the data related to the github user when I get my user object. How can I get access to the user with OAuth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at this sample code, do you capture the Github profile data onCreateUser?

**EDIT: this is server side code, e.g. server/accounts.js**

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function (options, user) {
    var accessToken = user.services.github.accessToken,
        result,
        profile;
    result = Meteor.http.get("https://api.github.com/user", {
        params: {
            access_token: accessToken
        }
    });
    if (result.error)
        throw result.error;

    profile = _.pick(result.data,
        "login",
        "name",
        "avatar_url",
        "url",
        "company",
        "blog",
        "location",
        "email",
        "bio",
        "html_url");

    user.profile = profile;

    return user;
});
```

[Code found here](http://www.zhgzw.com/4821290/codep2/custom-github-login-with-meteor-is-not-working)

Comment: this goes serverside?

Comment: very helpful, thank you sir. If I wanted it to run each login, can I just attach it to a different event handler?

Comment: If the user chooses not to display their email publicly the above returned result email field will be empty. If you really need the email another http request to `/user/emails` is needed to access to the email address.